# Controller action is not called in view using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am very much new in MVC. I have javascript function that reads xml string and displays various values. One of the element in XML is in encrypted form. I have written method in controller that will return decrypted string but I am not able to call that method inside my javascript method using ajax. Below the code of controller method and javascript code.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult DecryptMessage(string message)
 {
       string decryptedMessage= Encryption.DecryptData(message);
       return Json(decryptedMessage);
 }
```

part of Javascript code

```
if ((x[i].nodeName).toUpperCase() == "MESSAGE" ) {
           //alert(childnd.nodeValue);
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { value: childnd.nodeValue },
          url: "/QueryController/DecryptMessage",
          dataType:"string",
          Success: function (result) {
          if (result > 0) {
               stringDetails = stringDetails + '<br><strong>Value:</strong>' + result + '<br>';
            }

          })
       }
```

I am not able to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: what kind of HTTP error returns your request?

Comment: @Nicolai. How can I check that?

Comment: You better remove the `dataType`, especially when you're expecting JSON in return. Should be `dataType: "json"` or just remove it altogether, it will be handled automatically.

Comment: In developer console of the browser, try to press F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I

Comment: @Chirag Fanse If you are using Chrome, you can press F12 and go to Developer Tools > Network > Response and look for the request that you made.

Comment: And also, change `data: { value: childnd.nodeValue },` to `data: { message : childnd.nodeValue },`

Comment: If I keep watch on "result", then I am getting,"result" is undefined. I tried suggestion of Ormi Aharon

Comment: You sending back json, so it needs to be `dataType:"json",` (and it needs to be `data: { message : childnd.nodeValue },` as @OmriAharon noted.

Comment: @StephenMuecke. I tested that as well.

Comment: Then there must be an error showing in your console. Just test it with `return Json("This works");`

Comment: Do you have a virtual directory or are you working straight on localhost ?

Comment: @OmriAharon. Not getting your question. I have created virtual directory in my IIs for my code folder.

Comment: I mean if you're working with IIS or something and your URL is `http://localhost/MyApplication` or something like that, in which case `url: "/QueryController/DecryptMessage"` will not work.

Comment: @OmriAharon. This is the URL when I run application from my local iis i.e. localhost. http://localhost/LogViewerPortal/Query/Index. What I mean by url: "/QueryController/DecryptMessage" is my DecryptMessage() is in QueryController.cs file. Class name inside this file is also the same. NOTE. Index and DecryptMessage() both methods are in same class

Comment: I understand. Try with `url: "/LogViewerPortal/Query/DecryptMessage"`

Comment: I edited DecryptMessage(). Now it only has "return Jason("This works");". If I call this action from browser, I am getting resource not found error.
This is how I called.
http://localhost/LogViewerPortal/Query/DecryptMessage
And error I got is cannot found /LogViewerPortal/Query/DecryptMessage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71001/discussion-between-omri-aharon-and-chirag-fanse).

Comment: Have you tried just calling the index action on this controller without any parameters and see if it finds it? If it does then it's more than likely a routing issue.

Comment: Do you really have a controller named `QueryControllerController`? ALWAYS use the helpers to construct your url's `url: '@Url.Action("DecryptMessage", "QueryController")',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is your URL that you work on: `localhost/LogViewerPortal/Query/Index`, your AJAX should fire to the same URL. Also, change `Success` to `success`:

```
if ((x[i].nodeName).toUpperCase() == "MESSAGE" ) {
           //alert(childnd.nodeValue);
          $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { message : childnd.nodeValue },
          url: "/LogViewerPortal/Query/DecryptMessage",
          success: function (result) {
          if (result) {
               stringDetails = stringDetails + '<br><strong>Value:</strong>' + result + '<br>';
            }

          })
       }
```

And if you want to return a string from your controller, you could change to:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult DecryptMessage(string message)
 {
       string decryptedMessage= Encryption.DecryptData(message);
       return Content(decryptedMessage);
 }
```